# Flow Builder How to populate the Picklist Component default value for a Screen Element

Tags: lightning, visual-workflow, picklist

How to populate a default Picklist Component value for a Screen?

For instance, when I do a text input box I can provide a merge field into the default value box. When I click on the default value box for the picklist component the only option that comes up is "No Default Value".

In this screenshot I am populating the text input with {!Get_Online_Request.description__c}. Is there a similar configuration available for picklists?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do that with the picklist component that's built into Flow Builder, but you can install [Quick Choice](https://unofficialsf.com/quick-choice-improved-picklists-and-radio-buttons-for-flow/), which allows the use of merge fields as default values.